# Django queryset with multiple m2m fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have these models:

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
  coopsort = ManyToManyField('Cooperation', related_name='coopsort')
  name = models.CharField(...)

class Cooperation(models.Model):
  doctor = models.ManyToManyField(Doctor, blank=True, verbose_name=u"Doc")
```

How can I query all Cooperations for a given doctor using the coopsort m2m field?

```
Cooperation.objects.filter... <pls advise here>
```

Comment: why do you need manytomany in both the models ?

Comment: both have different functional reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is was so much easier than I expected. This worked for me:

```
doc # Doctor instance 
SelectedCooperations = doc.coopsort.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define a `ManyToManyField` in both models. If you need it in the `Doctor` model:

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    coopsort = ManyToManyField('Cooperation', related_name='coopsort')
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Cooperation(models.Model):
    cooperation_name = ...
```

then you can filter `cooperations` like so:

by doctor id

```
cooperations = Cooperation.objects.filter(doctor__id=1)
```

by doctor name

```
cooperations = Cooperation.objects.filter(doctor__name='John')
```

Comment: Thanks but I need the structure for a query that utilizes the m2m-field on the doctor model.

Answer (score 0):

```
doc # Doctor instance
queryset1 = doc.coopsort.all()
queryset2 = Cooperation.objects.filter(doctor=doc).all()
queryset = queryset1 | queryset2
```

`related_name` not work in m2m